# Два LEFT JOIN в запросе

Tags: mysql

Есть запрос:

```
SELECT `charges`.*, 
                DATE_FORMAT(`CHARGE_DATE`, '%b %e, %Y') AS `DATE`,
                `groupclasses`.`CODE` AS `CLASS`, 
                IFNULL((SELECT SUM(`AMOUNT`) FROM `payments_to_charges` 
                            WHERE `CHARGE_ID`=`charges`.`ID`),'0.00') AS `AMOUNT_PAID`, 
                CONCAT(IFNULL(FIRSTNAME,''),' ', IFNULL(LASTNAME,'')) AS CLIENT
            FROM `charges` 
                LEFT JOIN `groupclasses` ON (`charges`.`CLASS_ID`=`groupclasses`.`ID`),             
                `members`
            WHERE 
                `charges`.`MEMBER_ID`=`members`.`ID` AND
                `charges`.`ID` > 0  AND `charges`.`MEMBER_ID`= '1031'
```

пробую его расширить:

```
SELECT `charges`.*, 
                DATE_FORMAT(`CHARGE_DATE`, '%b %e, %Y') AS `DATE`,
                `groupclasses`.`CODE` AS `CLASS`, 
                IFNULL((SELECT SUM(`AMOUNT`) FROM `payments_to_charges` 
                            WHERE `CHARGE_ID`=`charges`.`ID`),'0.00') AS `AMOUNT_PAID`, 
                CONCAT(IFNULL(FIRSTNAME,''),' ', IFNULL(LASTNAME,'')) AS CLIENT,
                    CONCAT(IFNULL(members2.FIRSTNAME,''),' ', IFNULL(members2.LASTNAME,'')) AS STUDENT
            FROM `charges` 
                LEFT JOIN `groupclasses` ON (`charges`.`CLASS_ID`=`groupclasses`.`ID`),
                left join `members` as `members2` on(`charges`.`STUDENT_ID` = members2.ID),
                `members`
            WHERE 
                `charges`.`MEMBER_ID`=`members`.`ID` AND
                `charges`.`ID` > 0  AND `charges`.`MEMBER_ID`= '1031'
```

В итоге выдаёт ошибку. В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: А что за ошибка?

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'left join `members` as `members2` on(`charges`.`STUDENT_ID` = members2.ID),
                ' at line 10

Comment: Запятая после первого left join не нужна. Запомните все join пишутся без запятых. ибо запятая это скрытый вид слова join.

Answer (score 1):

В итоге сделал всё через join:

```
SELECT `charges`.*, 
                DATE_FORMAT(`CHARGE_DATE`, '%b %e, %Y') AS `DATE`,
                `groupclasses`.`CODE` AS `CLASS`, 
                IFNULL((SELECT SUM(`AMOUNT`) FROM `payments_to_charges` 
                            WHERE `CHARGE_ID`=`charges`.`ID`),'0.00') AS `AMOUNT_PAID`, 
                CONCAT(IFNULL(members.FIRSTNAME,''),' ', IFNULL(members.LASTNAME,'')) AS CLIENT,
                    CONCAT(IFNULL(members2.FIRSTNAME,''),' ', IFNULL(members2.LASTNAME,'')) AS STUDENT
            FROM `charges`
            inner join  `members` on `charges`.`MEMBER_ID`=`members`.`ID`
                LEFT JOIN `groupclasses` ON (`charges`.`CLASS_ID`=`groupclasses`.`ID`)
                left join `members` as `members2` on `charges`.`STUDENT_ID` = members2.ID
            WHERE                   
                `charges`.`ID` > 0  AND `charges`.`MEMBER_ID`= '1031'
```